# find rows that contain x numbers in a row

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need to find any rows in a table that have 16 numbers in a row.I need to make sure the users have not already inserted rows that contain a cc number. I am going to replace all spaces and dashes with empty string and manually inspect the rows to ensure i only act on appropriate ones.  We have several million rows and I need to narrow down the focus.

Comment: All these changes for a particular column or for all columns in a table? Give a schema of a table you've mentioned

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but if you have CC data just lying around, you might want to check out PCI before they talk to you https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/

Comment: @billinkc I know it is an old post, but the field in question was a free-form notes field. We did use common sense and not store credit cards (we validated them using a payment processor then stored the profile id for future use). The problem is some of the call center agents had keyed some numbers into the notes field and those needed to be cleaned up.

Comment: Common sense is never common in our field ;)

Comment: Unfortunately that is true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
...
WHERE column_name LIKE REPLICATE('[0-9]', 16);
```

If you want the ones that *are not* like a valid credit card number, then:

```
...
WHERE column_name NOT LIKE REPLICATE('[0-9]', 16);
```

Of course, remember that American Express cards only have 15 digits. So to incorporate that, you may want instead:

```
...
WHERE column_name LIKE REPLICATE('[0-9]', 16)
OR column_name LIKE '3' + REPLICATE('[0-9]', 14);
```

**EDIT** Based on t-clausen.dk's interpretation of the problem, where the OP hasn't already replaced dashes and spaces, you may need:

```
...
WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(column_name, '-', ''),' ','') LIKE ...
```

Comment: Why are you adding the % sign? The OP stated they are already replacing all the dashes and spaces. This means your clause will match for `12345678abcd901234rr56xx` and I don't think that's what the OP wants.